Did God lead the Israelites into slavery?
“And Israel took his journey with all that he had, and came to Beer-sheba, and offered sacrifices unto the God of his father Isaac. And God spake unto Israel in the visions of the night, and said, Jacob, Jacob. And he said, Here am I. And he said, I am God, the God of thy father: fear not to go down into Egypt; for I will there make of thee a great nation: I will go down with thee into Egypt; and I will also surely bring thee up again: and Joseph shall put his hand upon thine eyes.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭46‬:‭1‬-‭4‬ ‭KJV‬‬

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the pupose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archives of question/answer contributions as to how this plays out in practice. No, it was men who oppressed the Hebrews. But God's purpose and promise (which he expressed to Jacob as you note) was not frustrated and, eventually, was fulfilled. You seem to me to imply a disingenuity in the Deity, unless I have misunderstood your question.

I was just wondering why He would lead them to a place where He knew they would be enslaved.
After reading the comments, I am actually answered. Now I am seeing the slavery wasn’t why He led them there, he led them there for what He promised. It just so happened that they got enslaved.

Short Answer: No. At least, the scripture does not say that God lead the Israelites into slavery.
Why did the Israelites go to Egypt? The Israelites went to Egypt initially because of a severe famine in their own land. Additionally, scripture notes that they were well received because Joseph, Jacob’s son, had risen to a high position in Pharaoh’s court.
However, the leadership in Egypt changed and the Israelites were enslaved (Exodus 1:8-14).
God’s promise to Jacob included:

He would be with them.
He would bring them back to their land.

We see later that God led the Israelites out of Egypt under the leadership of Moses, in what we call the Exodus.
So what? God did allow the Israelites to go into Egypt where they eventually became enslaved. However, it was part of a larger plan for their growth as a nation and their eventual liberation and return to the land God had promised them. What do I mean by that? Shockingly, there was actually a benefit to being enslaved.

Population: In Egypt, the Israelites were able to grow from a
family of 70 (Exodus 1:5) into a large nation, as God had promised
Abraham (Genesis 15:5). This was due to the fertile land of Goshen. Where
they settled provided the resources necessary for this growth.
Cultural and religious isolation: Being in Egypt
likely reduced the Israelites’ ability to intermarry with other groups.
In fact, the Egyptians generally looked down upon shepherds (Genesis 46:34),
which helped to keep the Israelites separate. This cultural
isolation likely helped the Israelites maintain their distinct
identity as God's own people and their religious practices.

Here's how I'll conclude: God did not cause their enslavement, but He did use the situation to fulfill what was promised, demonstrate His power, and display His faithfulness to His people.

Makes sense, thanks!

@FadzaiMushangweMunhenga If this possibly answered your question, consider upvoting and marking it as answered by clicking the checkmark!
